# cannot add direct child error after deploying fiori app to system

Tags: xml, sapui5

i created a fiori app based on this [sap sample.](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.tnt.ToolPage/sample/sap.tnt.sample.ToolPageHorizontalNavigation)
testing the app in vscode works fine but after deploying it to the abap system and trying to run it from fiori launchpad i get hit with this error:
[image]

i tried playing around with the tags but only ended up breaking stuff, am glad for any help on this! thanks

heres my code:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="grcruletest.controller.Master"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt"
    xmlns:f="sap.f" 
    xmlns:variants="sap.ui.comp.variants" 
    xmlns:filterbar="sap.ui.comp.filterbar" 
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1">
    <tnt:ToolPage id="toolPage">
        <tnt:subHeader>
            <tnt:ToolHeader>
                <IconTabHeader
                        selectedKey="page1"
                        select=".onItemSelect"
                        mode="Inline">
                    <layoutData>
                        <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" shrinkable="true" />
                    </layoutData>
                    <items>
                        <IconTabFilter text="Compliance Engine" key="page1"/>
                        <IconTabFilter text="Rulebook Editor" key="page2"/>
                        <IconTabFilter text="Protokolle" key="page3"/>
                    </items>
                </IconTabHeader>
            </tnt:ToolHeader>
        </tnt:subHeader>
        <tnt:mainContents>
            <NavContainer id="pageContainer" initialPage="page1">
                <pages>
                    <ScrollContainer
                        id="page1"
                        horizontal="false"
                        vertical="true"
                        height="100%">
                        <mvc:XMLView id="compliance" viewName="grcruletest.view.compliance" />
                    </ScrollContainer>
                    <ScrollContainer
                        id="page2"
                        horizontal="false"
                        vertical="true"
                        height="100%">
                        <mvc:XMLView id="rulebook" viewName="grcruletest.view.rulebook" />
                    </ScrollContainer>
                    <ScrollContainer
                        id="page3"
                        horizontal="false"
                        vertical="true"
                        height="100%">
                        <mvc:XMLView id="protocols" viewName="grcruletest.view.protocols" />
                    </ScrollContainer>
                </pages>
            </NavContainer>
        </tnt:mainContents>
    </tnt:ToolPage>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: What version of SAP (or Open?) UI5 did you use on local and on Fiori Launchpad ?

Comment: local uses 1.116.0 (built at 12.07.2023 12:33:00) and fiori launchpad uses 1.71.55 (Build von 22.03.2023 11:03:00)